# Macro cuts and paste whole row below data loop

Tags: vba, excel

I have a report that lists the sales for a salesperson for the month. When the type of sale is "Open", the cell in column D will start with O (Open order, open layaway, etc). I can't include the open orders in the subtotal for their monthly sales, but instead have the opens orders in a separate section below their sales in a section called "Open Orders".

So what I need the macro to do is whenever a cell in column D starts with an O, *cut* whole row and *insert* (needs to be insert so their isn't blanks when pasting) paste below the data. This will shift the data since we are inserting. The problem that I'm having is that the macro will continue to cut and paste even though we have gone through all the rows in the data set.

```
Sub MoveOPENS()

'this is what im using to establish the last row in the data set
  Cells(1, 1).Select
  Selection.End(xlDown).Select
  nRowMax = Selection.Row

For i = 2 To nRowMax
    sItem = Cells(i, 4)

    Do While Left(sItem, 1) = "O"
        Rows(i).Select
        Selection.Cut
    'moves the cursor to below the data set
        Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
        Selection.End(xlDown).Select
        Selection.Offset(4, 0).Select
    'this part works well but it thinks the loop doesn't stop 
    'and will start copy and pasting below the new data section
    Selection.Insert
        sItem = Cells(i, 4)
    Loop
Next i

End Sub
```

How can i get the macro to know when we have reached the last row so it doesn't continue cutting and paste the rows we just copied and pasted? let me know if you need more details

[Here is what the excel sheet looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tc3mt.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you don't mind that I re-wrote the code from scratch.  It looks like you might have recorded a macro to do this, which is a good place to start when you are not sure how to approach it, but it also produces some very inefficient and confusing code sometimes.

Anyway, this should work for you:

```
Sub MoveOPENS()

Dim LastRow, NewLast, MovedCount As Integer

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Find last Row
NewLast = LastRow + 1 'NewLast tracks the new last row as rows are copied and pasted at the end
MovedCount = 0
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If Left(Cells(i, 4), 1) = "O" Then    'Copy the row, increment NewLast and paste at the bottom.
            Rows(i).Cut
            'LastRow = LastRow - 1
            Cells(NewLast, 1).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Rows(i).Delete
            i = i - 1  'Since we deleted the row, we must decrement i
            MovedCount = MovedCount + 1  'Keeps track of number of rows moved so as not to overshoot the original last line

        End If
        If i + MovedCount = LastRow Then Exit For 'Exit For loop if we reached the original last line of the file
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I think my issue with what i was doing was trying to have the code cut copy and insert paste which was shifting the data. I am going to forgo that method and go with yours while sticking an If statement that will delete the rows we just pasted. Thanks!

Comment: No problem.  If my answer worked for you, I would appreciate it if you would accept my answer.  This also helps the community so that everyone can focus on questions that are not already answered.  Thanks.

Comment: so my plan to use an if statement to delete the rows we just copied didn't work.. So since your code doesn't _cut_ and copy, its not going to work for this scenario. if your code is able to _cut_ and paste below data while dealing with the resulting shifting of the data, than that would be more what I'm looking for!

Comment: I revised my answer to include cutting and deleting of the data, while accounting for the shift.

Comment: ok that worked but when it gets to the last row, the macro doesn't want to end (Not Responding) unless i end it. Not sure if it is continuing to check the data and isn't sure when to stop the if?

Comment: You are correct.  I had the check for hitting the last line within the original if statement, so it only worked when the last row was a row that qualified to be moved.  I happened to have it that way in my test data, so it worked.  I edited the code again and you should be good now.

Answer (score 0):

Since you cut rows your nRowMax gets meaningless. Say, you have 1000 rows, but you cut 100 of them, so eventually you'll have 900 rows but you still try to loop through between 901st and 1000nd rows as well.

as a solution, you could create your loop as a do loop instead of for loop, like below.

```
Sub MoveOPENS()

    Dim sItem As String

    Cells(2, 1).Select
    r = 1
    Do
        sItem = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value

        If Left(sItem, 1) = "O" Then
            r = ActiveCell.Row
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
            Selection.Cut
            'moves the cursor to below the data set
            Cells(1000000, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
            Selection.Insert
            Cells(r, 1).Select
        Else
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        End If

Loop Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)

End Sub
```

Comment: You're right about the cutting and pasting messing with the nRowMax... However, when i try to change it to a do loop instead of a for loop, I'm getting a "Loop without Do" error. Can you show me what part of my code needs to be left out and where i should put that "Do" part?

Comment: i've just edited my answer to include the whole code

Comment: Thanks for including the whole code.. Your code makes the most sense given the fact that I am having problems with the data set shifting. The code seems to ignore the selection cut-> copy part... so it just continues checking column D all the way without doing anything

Comment: could u put your source data or its image on github or onedrive?

Comment: i added a picture to my original post.. if you need me to put the source data to Onedrive i can go ahead and do that

Comment: now i've changed my code again and tried accordin to your pic, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Sub MoveOPENS()

    Dim lRowMax As Long
    Dim sItem As String


'this is what im using to establish the last row in the data set
    Cells(1, 1).Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    lRowMax = Selection.Row

    For i = 2 To lRowMax
        sItem = Cells(i, 4).Value

        If Left(sItem, 1) = "O" Then
            Rows(i).Select
            Selection.Cut
            'moves the cursor to below the data set
            Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
            Selection.End(xlDown).Select
            Selection.Offset(4, 0).Select
            'this part works well but it thinks the loop doesn't stop
            'and will start copy and pasting below the new data section
            Selection.Insert
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: This still produced the same issue i was having before. @ExcelinEfendisi was right that the cut and paste is making the lRowMax ineffective