# If there is no data below header delete header

Tags: vba, excel

So I have a macro that cuts and copies "open orders" and inserts those lines below data [(See previous post)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46185007/macro-cuts-and-paste-whole-row-below-data-loop), after that it sticks a header above the open order data. The way the macro is written currently, if there are no open order data it sticks the header all the way down to row 65k.

See code below:

```
Dim LastRow, NewLast, MovedCount As Integer
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Find last Row
NewLast = LastRow + 1 'NewLast tracks the new last row as rows are copied and pasted at the end
    MovedCount = 0
 For I = 2 To LastRow
    If Left(Cells(I, 4), 1) = "O" Then    'Copy the row, increment NewLast and paste at the bottom.
        Rows(I).Cut
        'LastRow = LastRow - 1
        Cells(NewLast + 3, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Rows(I).Delete
        I = I - 1  'Since we deleted the row, we must decrement i
        MovedCount = MovedCount + 1  'Keeps track of number of rows moved so as not to overshoot the original last line

      End If
    If I + MovedCount = LastRow Then Exit For 'Exit For loop if we reached the original last line of the file
Next I

'inserts a header for the open section
Cells(1, 1).Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
nRowMax = Selection.Row
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.EntireRow.Copy
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Selection.Offset(-1, 0).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
ActiveCell.Select
ActiveCell = "Open Orders"
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

So my question is how can I either keep the header from being copied if there is no open order data or delete the header if there is no data around it.

I was thinking of putting an IF there is no data below header THAN delete header. Sorry if this is somewhat open ended i think there are a couple ways to go about this.

See images below to give you an idea what the data looks like with and without the open orders.[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, then if there are no open orders, you don't want the "Open Orders" header to populate at all. You can accomplish this by nesting the entire bottom section of code in an if statement:

```
If MovedCount <> 0 Then
  Cells(1, 1).Select
  ...
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
End If
```